# tor won't connect (mac)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

so since two days i get this error message :

"Tor unexpectedly exited. This might be due to a bug in Tor itself, another program on your system, or faulty hardware...."
when i click the restart button it simply pops up again.
because i am a novocaine i would like to hear your opinions on the topic. i can't copy the log to my clipboard as he shows that 0 logs were copied.
i already read a lot regarding that topic but i can't find my torrc file also.
Also there is no file directory regarding the torrc file neither in ~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data nor in the program directory itself.
whole thing seems very strange because i did not make any major adjustments on my mac. so there might be several options / possibilities regarding my topic but since i'm not that much into the technical side i would really appreciate it if you could drop some thoughts on this one.

cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same problem, can someone help

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13434)